# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property, Hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate

For some reason hibernate generator creates the wrong mappings (annotations). No, there are no errors, and the situation is as follows:

I have a table many-to-many with additional column and I want to put there data (data not recorded and no errors or queries).

Maybe someone know solution? If u dont know read below

---

I did the same as on the link below (not that I would want to advertise page)

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/
(author of the above page itself notes that the generator is not working as it should).

I did the same thing on, but I have this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.dms.entity.InventoryOrder.inventory in com.dms.entity.Inventory.inventoryOrders
```

Following code

Inventory

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVENTORY")
public class Inventory implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String symbol;
    private Set<InventoryOrder> inventoryOrders = new HashSet<InventoryOrder>(0);


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mysequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", mysequence= "SEQ_INV")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "SYMBOL", length = 32)
    public String getSymbol() {
        return this.symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "inventory")
    public Set<InventoryOrder> getInventoryOrders() {
        return this.inventoryOrders;
    }

    public void setInventoryOrders(Set<InventoryOrder> inventoryOrders) {
        this.inventoryOrders = inventoryOrders;
    }

}
```

StorageOrder

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STORAGEORDER")
public class Storageorder implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String code;
    private Set<InventoryOrder> inventoryOrders = new HashSet<InventoryOrder>(0);


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mysequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mysequence", sequenceName = "SEQ_STO")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "CODE", length = 32)
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "storageorder")
    public Set<InventoryOrder> getInventoryOrders() {
        return this.inventoryOrders;
    }

    public void setInventoryOrders(Set<InventoryOrder> inventoryOrders) {
        this.inventoryOrders = inventoryOrders;
    }

}
```

InventoryOrder

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVENTORY_ORDER")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "storageorder", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STORAGEORDERID")), <-- I have tried here put "ID", but same error
    @AssociationOverride(name = "inventory", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INVENTORYID")) }) <-- I have tried here put "ID", but same error
public class InventoryOrder implements java.io.Serializable {

    private InventoryOrderId id = new InventoryOrderId();
    private Long quantity;

    @EmbeddedId
    public InventoryOrderId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(InventoryOrderId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public Storageorder getStorageorder() {
        return getId().getStorageorder();
    }

    public void setStorageorder(Storageorder storageorder) {
        getId().setStorageorder(storageorder);
    }

    @Transient
    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return getId().getInventory();
    }

    public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
        getId().setInventory(inventory);
    }

    @Column(name = "QUANTITY", precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public Long getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        InventoryOrder that = (InventoryOrder) o;

        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(that.getId())
                : that.getId() != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0);
    }

}
```

InventoryOrderId

```
@Embeddable
public class InventoryOrderId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Storageorder storageorder;
    private Inventory inventory;

    @ManyToOne
    public Storageorder getStorageorder() {
        return this.storageorder;
    }

    public void setStorageorder(Storageorder storageorder) {
        this.storageorder = storageorder;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return this.inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        InventoryOrderId that = (InventoryOrderId) o;

        if (storageorder != null ? !storageorder.equals(that.storageorder)
                : that.storageorder != null)
            return false;
        if (inventory != null ? !inventory.equals(that.inventory)
                : that.inventory != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (storageorder != null ? storageorder.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (inventory != null ? inventory.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Soft: (Hibernate 4.2.15, Spring 3.2.9, Oracle 11g)

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the example you're following (the link), you'll notice that both the association overrides and the mapped-by annotations use a 'dotted name'. This is used to reference fields of a field transitively. In your case, you need to add 'id.' in both places before 'inventory' and 'storageorder'.

Comment: The second option, If i do like below
@AssociationOverride(name = "id.storageorder", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STORAGEID")), @AssociationOverride(name = "id.inventory", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "INVENTORYID"))
and when i try put some data then error:
 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DATABASENAME"."INVENTORY_ORDER"."STORAGEORDERID")